# How can I get rid of mysterious warning: "'../project.csprojAssemblyReference.cache' already exists"?

Tags: msbuild

I have the following warning when building some of my class library csprojs:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2110,5): warning MSB3101: Could not write state file "..\..\tmp\dotnet\anvil.controls\obj\vs2017\net461\debug
\anvil.controls.vs2017.net461.csprojAssemblyReference.cache". The file 'E:\anvil\Anvil.Controls\tmp\dotnet\anvil.controls\obj\vs2017\net461\debug\Anvil.Controls.vs2017.net461.csprojAssemblyReference.cache' already exists. [E:\anvil\Anvil.Controls\src\anvil.controls\anvil.controls.vs2017.net461.csproj]
```

- I've tried using msbuild 15.0 (VS2017 and Standalone 2.2.103) and 16.0.
- Same warning in Visual Studio 2017 and JetBrains.Rider
- Does not happen if I wipe my temp folder. Then happens in subsequent builds or even rebuilds.
- Happens to a subset of my projects, only similarity I can see is that they are all projects that contain .xaml files. But it doesn't happen on all projects with .xaml files.
- Happens when I use `-maxcpucount:1` (to disable parallel build).
- Each project has a unique tmp/intermediate folder, set to this: `..\..\tmp\dotnet\ubisoft.controls\<bin|obj>\vs2017\net45\<debug|release>\`

Any ideas what might affect this error in my projects?

Comment: Could you clarify what kind of build customization you performed to use a custom intermediate output path (temp folder)? the file names of the cache files seem off

Comment: Added the tmp/intermediate paths to my question. Thx!

Comment: Only `IntermediateOutputPath` or `BaseIntermediateOutputPath` as well?

Comment: Only `IntermediateOutputPath` is set in my .csproj file.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes *'mysterious warnings'* (and errors) come from too long paths. Try to use a shorter output path, i.e.

```
E:\build\Anvil.Controls\tmp\net461\debug\
```

instead of

```
E:\anvil\Anvil.Controls\tmp\dotnet\anvil.controls\obj\vs2017\net461\debug\
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9635709/1728692) as well